# Max numbers of connections / threads on my TCP / IP server?

Tags: windows, linux, tcp

I am curious about whether my server would work better on Linux or Windows, from what I have read Windows only supports around 2,000 connections/threads while I have not seen much information about how many threads / connections Linux can handle.

Is there any advantages to using Linux over Windows other than stability / security for my TCP /IP server?

Thanks.

Comment: Linux (with Apache or Lighttpd, and often PHP & MySQL) is powering the majority of internet servers today. It could tell something....

Comment: Linux and Apache are behind many sites, but some large sites are run on Windows, like the StackExchange network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Threads and sockets are different resources, the limits for each will depend not just on `Linux` vs `Windows` but also which versions of each OS you are using. Also, if you're using a class library instead of raw socket or thread APIs, those might impose a specific limit. As an example early versions of CSocket in MFC created a hidden window for each socket, so you were effectively limited to the number of GDI resources on the system.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. I'll just go with Windows, I hope C# will support what I want to do.

Answer (score 2):

Either platform will be fine, and most apps will never get big enough to need more than a single server to run them anyway.  Get your project done in whichever way is easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that the primary concern when building a high-scale application is the experience of the engineers on your team, including operations engineers. By all means *consider* performance when selecting a platform, but the experience and preference of your development and operations engineers is probably more important - after all, they will need to maintain and operate the service respectively.

In any case, if you have a real need for a service with 2000 concurrent clients, it probably has some high availability requirement which means it can't be run on a single server anyway.